# Oracle SQL grouping to one row

Tags: sql, oracle

I have the following table

```
+---------+----------+------------+------------+----------+----------+
| PN      | code     | date       | F2         | PO       | Supplier |
+---------+----------+------------+------------+----------+----------+
| CDS0055 | NBR00008 | 16.06.2017 | 19.06.2017 | 9872786  | S00021XC |
| CDS0055 | NBR00008 | 16.06.2017 | 03.07.2017 |          | S00021XC |
| CDS0055 | NBR00008 | 16.06.2017 | 04.07.2017 |          | S0000000 |
+---------+----------+------------+------------+----------+----------+
```

and I want to get this result (group min (f2)):

```
+---------+----------+------------+------------+---------+----------+
| PN      | code     | date       | F2         | PO      | Supplier |
+---------+----------+------------+------------+---------+----------+
| CDS0055 | NBR00008 | 16.06.2017 | 19.06.2017 | 9872786 | S00021XC |
+---------+----------+------------+------------+---------+----------+
```

Query:

```
select distinct PN, min(f2), date, PO, siplier from Order
group by pn, po, date, supplier
```

Comment: Please format your data so that is is readable.  What is our question?  Please show expected output.

Comment: Why that row and not `19.06.2017` which is the minimum value for `F2`?

Comment: Your sample data has two `PO` columns.

Comment: Sorry! It's my first post on here. I have no idea, how can I format the table to be readable.

Answer (score 0):

You can get the minimum value for a column within each group (and all the other corresponding values) using the `ROW_NUMBER()` analytic function:

```
SELECT *
FROM   (
  SELECT t.*,
         ROW_NUMBER() OVER (
             PARTITION BY pn,po,"date",supplier
             ORDER BY f2
         ) AS rn
  FROM   your_table t
)
WHERE  rn = 1
```